# What I need write in this line instead dot when I remake pure React to Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `React` app where I make request to server and get response - `category list`. This app also have some functionality (**pagination**, **filtering by title**, **choose quanity category** on page, **sort by asc-desc**). Now I need remake small part to `Redux`. But I just started learning `Redux` and I dont know what I need write in two line in `Home.js` and in two line in `EditListReducer.js`. I mark place in this line like this:`.....`

First I write that I already wrote in **Redux** and below I wrote small part from my **React** app(wrote on pure React) which I remake to Redux.

## Wrote on REDUX:

I comment line when I dont know what I need write instead `.....`

#### Home.js:

```
const Home = () => {

useEffect(() => {
          fetchData(value.currentPage, value.quantityElementPage, value.sortAscDesc, value.searchInput); 
  }, [value.currentPage, value.quantityElementPage, value.sortAscDesc, value.searchInput]);
    
    function fetchData(valuePage, valueElement, valueSort, valueFilter, dispatch ) {
      return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
         dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_START", payload:  ....... });   // in this line 
             const data = await api(`pathWithQueryParams`, {
               method: 'GET',
             });
         dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_END", payload: ....... });     // in this line
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
        };
    }
```

#### EditListReducer.js:

```
const initialState = {
    listCategory: [],
    currentPage: 1, 
    quantityElementPage: 3,
    buttonsPagination: 0,   
    buttonsQuantityElementPage: 3,
    sortAscDesc: "asc",
    searchInput: ""
}

export function EditListReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOAD_DATA_START":
      return {...state,
        ......           //in this line 
     };
    case "LOAD_DATA_END":
      return {...state, 
          .......        // in this line 
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

### Wrote on REACT (small part which I remake to Redux):

```
const Home = () => {
    
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    listCategory: [],
    currentPage: 1, 
    quantityElementPage: 3,
    buttonsPagination: 0,   
    buttonsQuantityElementPage: 3,
    sortAscDesc: "asc",
    searchInput: ""
});
       
  useEffect(() => {
          fetchData(value.currentPage, value.quantityElementPage, value.sortAscDesc, value.searchInput); 
  }, [value.currentPage, value.quantityElementPage, value.sortAscDesc, value.searchInput]);
    
    async function fetchData(valuePage, valueElement, valueSort, valueFilter ) {  
      try {
        const data = await api(`pathWithQueryParams`, {
          method: 'GET',
         });
          setValue(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            listCategory: data.data,
            currentPage: data.page,
            buttonsPagination: Math.ceil(data.total / data.perPage),
            quantityElementPage: data.perPage,
         }));
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just maintain an `isLoading` value in state in the reducer, and the action "LOAD_DATA_START" alone is enough to know when data is loading. In the "LOAD_DATA_END" action you spread in the existing state ***and*** new data, and don't forget to toggle back the loading state.

**EditListReducer.js:**

```
const initialState = {
  listCategory: [],
  currentPage: 1,
  quantityElementPage: 3,
  buttonsPagination: 0,
  buttonsQuantityElementPage: 3,
  sortAscDesc: "asc",
  searchInput: "",
  isLoading: false // <-- add loading to state slice
};

export function EditListReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOAD_DATA_START":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true // <-- just set loading true
      };
    case "LOAD_DATA_END":
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload, // <-- spread in payload from action
        isLoading: false // <-- set loading false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Home.js:**

```
const Home = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(
      value.currentPage,
      value.quantityElementPage,
      value.sortAscDesc,
      value.searchInput
    );
  }, [
    value.currentPage,
    value.quantityElementPage,
    value.sortAscDesc,
    value.searchInput
  ]);

  function fetchData(
    valuePage,
    valueElement,
    valueSort,
    valueFilter,
    dispatch
  ) {
    return async dispatch => {
      try {
        dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_START" }); // <-- no need for payload, just action type

        const data = await api(`pathWithQueryParams`, {
          method: "GET"
        });

        // Construct payload
        const payload = {
          listCategory: data.data,
          currentPage: data.page,
          buttonsPagination: Math.ceil(data.total / data.perPage),
          quantityElementPage: data.perPage
        };
        dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_END", payload }); // <-- Pass payload
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    };
  }
};
```

*EDIT* Process payload in the reducer

**EditListReducer.js:**

```
const initialState = {
  listCategory: [],
  currentPage: 1,
  quantityElementPage: 3,
  buttonsPagination: 0,
  buttonsQuantityElementPage: 3,
  sortAscDesc: "asc",
  searchInput: "",
  isLoading: false // <-- add loading to state slice
};

export function EditListReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOAD_DATA_START":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true // <-- just set loading true
      };
    case "LOAD_DATA_END": {
      const { payload } = action;
      return {
        ...state,
        listCategory: payload.data,
        currentPage: payload.page,
        buttonsPagination: Math.ceil(payload.total / payload.perPage),
        quantityElementPage: payload.perPage
        isLoading: false // <-- set loading false
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Home.js:**

```
const Home = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(
      value.currentPage,
      value.quantityElementPage,
      value.sortAscDesc,
      value.searchInput
    );
  }, [
    value.currentPage,
    value.quantityElementPage,
    value.sortAscDesc,
    value.searchInput
  ]);

  function fetchData(
    valuePage,
    valueElement,
    valueSort,
    valueFilter,
    dispatch
  ) {
    return async dispatch => {
      try {
        dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_START" }); // <-- no need for payload, just action type

        const data = await api(`pathWithQueryParams`, {
          method: "GET"
        });

        dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_END", payload: data }); // <-- Pass data in payload
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: thank you very much! I see in one app that reducer wrote like this:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/0d2d9fd1faf11c96e3b0450e11163d5f/1588455460/36601/1372209/f.png
Can you besides the option that you propsed also demonstrate the option similar to the one in the screenshot which I send you? That is, what you put in the const payload was in the reducer file. No need to delete what you wrote, just add this to your answer. I just think that the person who will check my application will require that the payload be in the reducer. But your answer is great!

Comment: @erik If you refer to use of `action.payload` in the reducer then I updated my answer to include that as it was an oversight on my part, it needs to be extracted from the action object. If not then can you clarify a bit what you want me to extract from that screen shot?

Comment: I just thought the reducer should look something like this in my case: http://i.piccy.info/i9/5918394bf952725cb5b7ac3478c23cce/1588456566/65981/1372209/dd.png

Comment: @erik Ah, I see, you want/need the processing logic to be handled *in* the reducer versus being pre-processed... I'll add to answer.

Comment: Hello! Yesterday I couldn't do the code test that you wrote in answer. But today I did it. And now my list of categories does not appear on the page. I described the problem in more detail in my new question. Please see it when you have the time:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61575274/why-list-disappeared-when-i-remake-small-part-react-app-to-redux

Comment: Hello Drew! Can you look at my new question? There's a unique problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917300/after-renaming-a-few-folders-and-files-appears-errors-although-imports-and-expo