# Why list disappeared when I remake small part React app to Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have app wrote on `pure React` where I make request to server and get response - `category list`. But I needed to rework small part of my app.

### But when I remake this part my list dissapeared.

I tried write `console.log("My data look like:", data);` after `const data = await api('pathWithQueryParams', {`. to see if the data is coming. But I don't even see the text `My data look like:` in browser console. That is, in inside the function `fetchData` even `console.log` dont work.

First in my question I'll write code that I remake to **Redux**
and below after _______________________________
I'll write small part my app which **wrote on pure React**(before remake to redux) and work well.

## Wrote on REDUX:

#### Home.js:

```
const Home = () => {

  const listCategory = useSelector(state => state.filterListReducer.listCategory);
  const currentPage = useSelector(state => state.filterListReducer.currentPage);
  const quantityElementPage = useSelector(state => state.filterListReducer.quantityElementPage);
  const sortAscDesc = useSelector(state => state.filterListReducer.sortAscDesc);
  const searchInput = useSelector(state => state.filterListReducer.searchInput);

  useEffect(() => {
      fetchData(currentPage, quantityElementPage, sortAscDesc, searchInput); 
  }, [currentPage, quantityElementPage, sortAscDesc, searchInput]);
    
    async function fetchData(valuePage, valueElement, valueSort, valueFilter, dispatch ) {
      return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
          
          dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_START" }); 
          
          const data = await api(`pathWithQueryParams`, {   // <-- api - it function which using fetch make request to server
            method: 'GET',
           });
             console.log("My data look like:", data);   // <-- check if the data came in response, but I don't see even text "My data look like:" in browser console
    
          dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_END", payload: data }); 
        
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
     };
    }

return ( <div> <Table dataAttribute={listCategory} /> </div> ); };
```

## ___________________________________________________

### Wrote on pure React (before remake to redux):

```
const Home = () => {
    
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    listCategory: [],
    currentPage: 1, 
    quantityElementPage: 3,
    buttonsPagination: 0,   
    buttonsQuantityElementPage: 3,
    sortAscDesc: "asc",
    searchInput: ""
});
       
  useEffect(() => {
          fetchData(value.currentPage, value.quantityElementPage, value.sortAscDesc, value.searchInput); 
  }, [value.currentPage, value.quantityElementPage, value.sortAscDesc, value.searchInput]);
    
    async function fetchData(valuePage, valueElement, valueSort, valueFilter ) {  
      try {
        const data = await api(`pathWithQueryParams`, {
          method: 'GET',
         });
          setValue(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            listCategory: data.data,
            currentPage: data.page,
            buttonsPagination: Math.ceil(data.total / data.perPage),
            quantityElementPage: data.perPage,
         }));
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    }
```

Comment: How is `Home` connected to your redux store, i.e. where is `dispatch` being defined/provided?

Comment: It doesn't appear as though `Home` has been connected to your store, either by using the `connect` HOC or `useDispatch` redux react hook.

Comment: @Drew Reese user Kyr gave the correct answer, there just needed to remove word `async` before `async function fetchData`. Everything is working very well right now.
Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Great! I don't think specifying a function to be asynchronous would have that kind of effect but good to know it's resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Home.js fragment

useEffect(() => {
/* 
  fetchData(currentPage, quantityElementPage, sortAscDesc, searchInput); 

  invoke fetchData, but does not call returning function
  e.g. const actualFetching = fetchData(currentPage, quantityElementPage, sortAscDesc, searchInput);

and missing call actualFetching(dispatch);
*/
      fetchData(currentPage, quantityElementPage, sortAscDesc, searchInput)(dispatch); 


  }, [currentPage, quantityElementPage, sortAscDesc, searchInput]);

    async function fetchData(valuePage, valueElement, valueSort, valueFilter 
/*, dispatch - not necessary here */ ) {
/*
  returning function (dispatch) => {}
*/
      return async (dispatch) => {
        try {

          dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_START" }); 

          const data = await api(`pathWithQueryParams`, {   // <-- api - it function which using fetch make request to server
            method: 'GET',
           });
             console.log("My data look like:", data);   // <-- check if the data came in response, but I don't see even text "My data look like:" in browser console

          dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_END", payload: data }); 

      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
     };
    }
```

Comment: Error: `'dispatch' is not defined  no-undef ` in line: `fetchData(currentPage, quantityElementPage, sortAscDesc, searchInput)(dispatch);`

Comment: [useDispatch](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch) may help

Comment: @Kyr Your answer started working when in this line: `async function fetchData(valuePage, valueElement, valueSort, valueFilter) {`
I delete `async`

Comment: @Kyr Thank you very much! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
async function fetchData(valuePage, valueElement, valueSort, valueFilter, dispatch ) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {

      dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_START" }); 

      const data = await api(`pathWithQueryParams`, {   // <-- api - it function which using fetch make request to server
        method: 'GET',
       });
         console.log("My data look like:", data);   // <-- check if the data came in response, but I don't see even text "My data look like:" in browser console

      dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_END", payload: data }); 

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
 };
}
```

This function is now returning a function, I think you are trying to create a hook here so the way to probably do this is:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetch = fetchData();//this returns a function now
  fetch(currentPage, quantityElementPage, sortAscDesc, searchInput);
}, [currentPage, quantityElementPage, sortAscDesc, searchInput]);

function fetchData() {
  return async (valuePage, valueElement, valueSort, valueFilter, dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_START" });

      const data = await api(`pathWithQueryParams`, {
        // <-- api - it function which using fetch make request to server
        method: "GET"
      });
      console.log("My data look like:", data); // <-- check if the data came in response, but I don't see even text "My data look like:" in browser console

      dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_END", payload: data });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: `TypeError: fetch is not a function` in this line:
`fetch(currentPage, quantityElementPage, sortAscDesc, searchInput);`

Comment: sorry try again, just remove the `async` from the first function

Comment: there is no error but the list is still dont appear on the page ... and I dont see text `My data look like:` in console browser